# Make thumbnails persistent for the current session only, do not store them on the disk

Tags: mount, nautilus, icons, thumbnails, tmp

I don't want thumbnails stored on my disk (e.g. for privacy reasons), but completely disabling thumbnailing (by denying write access to `~/.cache/thumbnails`) also replaces all preview icons with those ugly "waiting for thumbnail generation" icons.

So how can I best configure my Ubuntu 16.04 (Unity DE) to generate thumbnails, but never store them on the disk, only in RAM?

I already have `/tmp` configured as a RAM disk (`/etc/fstab` entry mounting a `tmpfs` there), that could also be used for this, but other ways are welcome as well.

Comment: `mount -t tmpfs none ~/.cache/thumbnails` (IIRC, not sure of the options)? Or you could symlink `~/.cache/thumbnails` to something in `/dev/shm`, or you could use an overlayfs with the working/top directory in `/tmp`.

Comment: Be sure ***not to repeat the typo*** in your symbolic link from the other answer as I did by copy/paste! Use instead: `ln -s /dev/shm ~/.cache/thumbnails`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the moment I just made `~/.cache/thumbnails` a symlink to `/dev/shm` which is a RAM disk included on all Ubuntu systems since around kernel 2.6 or so... On my system it was only used by pulseaudio which placed some files in there, but nothing else.

I decided for this way because I then only need a symlink and not another mount entry in `/etc/fstab` or something like that. It's okay as all the single thumbnail images are stored in subfolders of the `thumbnails` directory anyway.

So the commands to set it up are:

```
rm -rf ~/.cache/thumbnails
ln -s /dev/shm ~/.cache/thumbnails
```

If you have a better option, feel free to post a different answer, I'm open to suggestions.